How to get the text from iOS AutoFill keyboard function in React Native?
I'm using react-native-otp-textinput for the otp input in my app. When I use the AutoFill from iOS keyboard to paste the code, the inputs doesn't get filled except the first input. The library only provided solution using copy-paste method. It seems that Clipboard.getString only return value when the text is copied.
Is there a way to retrieve the value from AutoFill for me to populate to the input?
import OTPTextInput from 'react-native-otp-textinput';

const handleCellTextChange = async (text: string, i: number) => {
    if (i === 0) {
        const clippedText = await Clipboard.getString();

        if (clippedText.slice(0, 1) === text) {
          codeRef.current?.setValue(clippedText, true);
        }
    }
};

return (
     <OTPTextInput
            ref={codeRef}
            inputCount={6}
            tintColor={Colour.MoodBlue}
            textInputStyle={styles.textCode}
            handleTextChange={(text: string) => setCode(text)}
            handleCellTextChange={handleCellTextChange}
            defaultValue={code}
     />
);

